# Extending objects with JQuery, Object has no method error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript code:

```
var TodoController = {

  init: function() {

    $(this).find('input.todo_check').click(function(){
      $(this).parents('li.todo').done();
    });

  }    
}

var Todo = {
  done: function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('done');
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("li.todo").extend(Todo);  
  $("#todo_list").extend(TodoController).init();

});
```

When I click on a 'input.todo_check' I expect done() function, on 'li.todo', to be executed. But I get:

=> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'done'

What I'm doing wrong?

This statement should add 'done()' function to "li.todo" elements?:

```
$("li.todo").extend(Todo);
```

Thanks.
JM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call `$(x)` (for any `x`), you get a brand new object. So these two statements:

```
var $x1 = $("li.todo");
var $x2 = $(this).parents('li.todo');
```

produce two completely difference objects. So if you do this:

```
var $x1      = $('li.todo');
$x1.where_is = 'pancakes house?';
```

And then later do this:

```
var $x2 = $(this).parents('li.todo');
```

Then `$x2` won't have a `where_is` property even if both `$x1` and `$x2` resolve to the same set of DOM objects.

Also, `$.extend` doesn't behave the way you think it does. Calling [`extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) merges the objects into the first object. So saying:

```
$(x).extend(Todo);
```

simply returns `Todo` without changing anything whereas:

```
$(x).extend(Todo, { where_is: 'pancakes house?' });
```

Adds a `where_is` property to `Todo` and returns the modified `Todo`. That's why you usually see `extend` used like this:

```
options = $.extend({ }, defaults, options);
```

Comment: Here is a working example https://gist.github.com/jmrepetti/ed6ed6065b59a0b016dc. Tanks for your help.